# Backbone Marionette 'itemViewContainer' not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

Working with Marionette for the first time and I've run into an issue with the 'itemViewContainer' attribute when I try and render a CompositeView.

I've gotten the CompositeView to work in the same app, but in this case I'm trying to render a 'PopupView' when the user clicks on a button. Within this popup, there's a table that's rendered by a CompositeView that's not appearing.

Here's the View in which the user can open the popup. This is an item in a CompositeView.

```
define([
    'marionette',
    'templates',
    'views/SectionPopupView'
], function(
    Marionette,
    templates,
    SectionPopupView
) {

  /** ClassListingRowView represents a row in the ClassListingView.
   *  Each Row is tied to a specific Course object that's passed in
   *  when the Row is instantiated in ClassListingView.
   *  this.model: Course model
   *  this.options.user: User model */
  return Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: templates.classListingRow,
    className: 'class-listing',
    popupView: null,

    ui: {
      'editBtn': 'a.edit-btn',
      'removeBtn': 'a.remove-btn',
      'popupContainer': 'div.popup-container'
    },

    events: {
      'click @ui.editBtn': 'editCourse',
      'click @ui.removeBtn': 'removeCourse'
    },

    /** Set the ID of this element to [UID]-listing. Also fetches data
     *  from the model. */
    // TODO: This calls render() twice... how do I make it better?
    initialize: function() {
      this.user = this.options.user;
      $(this.$el).attr('id', this.model.get('UID') + '-listing');

      var self = this;
      this.model.fetch({
        success: function() {
          self.render();
        }
      });
    },

    /** Spawns a popup with all sections that allows a user to choose
     *  which sections he/she does/doesn't want. */
    editCourse: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      var self = this;
      // Instantiate a view if it hasn't already been instantiated
      $(window.app.curtain).show();
      if (this.popupView == null) {
        this.popupView = new SectionPopupView({
          el: self.ui.popupContainer,
          model: self.model
        });
        this.popupView.render();
      } else {
        this.popupView.show();
      }
    },

    /** Removes this.course from the User's selectedCourse list.
     *  This will trigger an event which the ClassListingView should be
     *  listening for, and then this View will be discarded. */
    removeCourse: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      this.user.removeCourseFromSelected(this.model);
    }
  });
});
```

Here's the View of the popup:

```
define([
    'marionette',
    'templates',
    'views/PopupView',
    'views/SectionTableView',
    'jquery'
], function(
    Marionette,
    templates,
    PopupView,
    SectionTableView,
    $
) {

  /** A SectionPopupView is a View that represents a popup that shows all of
   *  the sections for a particular Course and allows a user to select
   *  which sections he wants to include and also to see more information
   *  about the course.
   *  model: Course */
  var SectionPopupView = PopupView.extend({
    template: templates.sectionPopup,
    sectionTable: null,

    ui: {
      'closeBtn': 'a.close',
      'tableContainer': 'div#table-container',
      'okBtn': 'a#submit'
    },

    events: {
      'click @ui.closeBtn': 'close',
      'click @ui.okBtn': 'continue'
    },

    /** Upon initialization, the View will have been instantiated with
     *  model: Course. A SectionListTableView must be instantiated upon
     *  init and populated with data from the model's sections attr. */
    initialize: function() {
      var self = this;
      this.on('render', function() {
        self.sectionTable.render();
      });
      this.sectionTable = new SectionTableView({
        el: self.ui.tableContainer,
        model: self.model
      });

      // this.sectionTable.render();
    },

    /** Hides the popup (and curtain). */
    show: function() {
      $(window.app.curtain).show();
      $(this.el).show();
    },

    /** Shows the popup (and curtain). */
    close: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      $(window.app.curtain).hide();
      $(this.el).hide();
    }
  });

  return SectionPopupView;
});
```

and here's the View for the table (sectionTable)

```
define([
    'marionette',
    'templates',
    'views/SectionTableRowView',
    'views/NoSectionsView',
    'jquery'
], function(
    Marionette,
    templates,
    SectionTableRowView,
    NoSectionsView,
    $
) {

  /**
   *  this.model = Course */
  return Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: templates.sectionTable,
    itemView: SectionTableRowView,
    itemViewContainer: 'tbody',
    emptyView: NoSectionsView,

    initialize: function() {
      this.itemViewOptions = {
        user: this.model
      };
    }
  });
});
```

I read on here that a lot of people had this issue because they were trying to render the view before it was in the DOM, so I binded the table's render function to the popup's render event, but that didn't work either. Any help?

Apart from that, am I doing anything incorrectly with regards to MVC guidelines/best practices/etc? I'm not 100% confident in my code, so feedback would be appreciated as well! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1) Your `this.on("render"...` code needs to be passed the right context (I believe this works):

```
this.on("render", function() {
  this.sectionTable.render();
}, this);
```

This whole bit could be moved to the `onRender` function of this view which helps with clarity:

```
onRender: function() {
  this.sectionTable.render();
}
```

2) It's important to understand what signals marionette uses around the DOM:

`onRender` methods get invoked when the `$el` for that view has been fully constructed in a virtual DOM but BEFORE it has been inserted into the user's (/jQuery accessible) DOM

`onShow` methods get invoked with the `$el` for that view is successfully in the DOM and is jQuery accessible.

There are some `onShow` edge cases that can come up which usually only happen if you are deeply nesting layouts. I wrote it up [here](http://averycodes.com/proper-and-improper-uses-of-marionettes-onshow-and-onrender/) if you are curious.

Comment: Thanks for the info about `onRender` vs `onShow`. I moved the code to `onRender`, but I'm still getting the 'itemViewContainer' not found error. I'm not using Regions to display the popup, so I don't have an onShow method.

Comment: To recap the problem: the SectionTable View is throwing up because it's unable to locate 'tbody' in its $el which is where it's expecting to do the itemView appending. Can you verify that you have a 'tbody' element specified in the template that's used for that view?

Comment: Sorry for such a late response – yes, there's definitely a `tbody` element in the template. Here I logged `this.template` in the `initialize` function and there's clearly a `tbody` inside, but I still get the error. http://d.pr/i/EA07